# Table 'database_name.username' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, database

I try to connect my html login file to phpmyAdmin database name "6470" - table "6470exercises" by this php file.

And the result is "Table '6470.username' doesn't exist". How can i resolve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', '6470');

define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL 1: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL 2: " . mysql_error());
/*
$ID = $_POST['user'];
$Password = $_POST['pass'];
*/

function SignIn()
{
    session_start(); //starting the session for user profile page
    if(!empty($_POST['user'])) //checking the 'user' name which is from Sign-In.html, is it empty or have some text
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
        if(!empty($row['userName']) AND !empty($row['pass']))
        {
            $_SESSION['userName'] = $row['pass']; echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGIN TO USER PROFILE PAGE...";
        } else {
            echo "SORRY... YOU ENTERED WRONG ID OR PASSWORD... PLEASE RETRY...";
        }
    }
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM UserName [...]` => Do you have a table named "username"? Or do you want to `SELECT * FROM 6470exercises`?

Comment: Please make sure that UserName table exists ?

Comment: Just a question, why is your users in separate tables, why not have one table with all users in them?

Comment: before you start debugging this, you really aught to swap to the `mysqli` driver, the `mysql` driver is deprecated.  You also need to be using prepared statements. As it stands, your code is extremely insecure.

Comment: Oh yah and Linux is case sensitive remember that

Comment: oh no i do not have any table named "username"
just a database named "6470" have a table named "6470exercises"

Comment: yes i want to SELECT * FROM 6470exercises
but when i replace "6470exercises" instead of "username"
they said "Unknown column 'pass' in 'where clause'"

Comment: ... Do you have any column named "pass" in `6470exercises` table? Please show your table structure.

Comment: oh i put wrong column name so this is not working :) i have just solve my problem, many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM UserName where userName = '$_POST[user]' AND pass = '$_POST[pass]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

with:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 6470exercises where userName = '{$_POST[user]}' AND pass = '{$_POST[pass]}'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Also enclose the $_POST request in the query with curly brackets {}

Comment: Good call, edited. So used to PDO that it never occurred to me.

Comment: they say "Unknown column 'pass' in 'where clause'"

Comment: You've got the wrong column name then. Find the name of the column where the password is stored in your database and replace 'pass' with whatever it is meant to be. Then it should work, or at least move forward a bit!

Comment: Well done!! thank you so much, my column contain username and password are USERNAME & PASSWORD_HASH and i replace all userName and pass instead of them

Comment: Well done to you too :) Always check your variable names, and look into either mysqli or pdo as more secure standards for interacting with a database - your current code is painfully insecure but if you are just learning don't worry I am sure future lessons will cover this.